# React Components on the Server

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I've been playing around with React for a while now but still can't wrap my head around on how to integrate it with an existing node/express/handlebars app.

For example, if I had a feed component which required json data to be fetched from AWS - how do I handle this.

```
var VideoFeed = require('./component/VideoFeed');

app.use('/', function(res, req) { 
    DataService.getVideoFeed().then(function(data) {
        res.render('home', {videoComponent: React.renderToString(<VideoFeed feed={data} />);
    });
});
```

Home

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    Some sample text.  Here's the Video Feed
    {{videoComponent}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to mix these? Unless you're going to do an "isomorphic " style render, using React adds quite a lot of overhead. It's not clear what you're asking specifically.

Comment: I thought isomorphic apps were the way to go in terms of performance?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to build. But, it doesn't look like you're building something isomorphic.  What is your programming question about code you've written?